# How is the proper way to use HighCharts with StencilJS?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, stenciljs

I have used HighCharts with React and that was quite straight-forward with the [React-Highcharts-Wrapper](https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/highcharts-react-wrapper/)

Now I'm learning to use Highcharts together with StencilJS, but can't get it to work, I don't really understand how to do. (I'm a coder coming from the design path, so I'm not a *real* programmer...)

This is what I have tried, inspired from the official tutorial:

```
import { Component, h } from "@stencil/core";
import * as Highcharts from "highcharts";

@Component({
  tag: "my-chart",
  styleUrl: "my-chart.scss",
  shadow: true,
})

export class MyChart {
  componentDidLoad() {
    var myChart = Highcharts.chart("container", {
      chart: {
        type: "bar",
      },
      title: {
        text: "Fruit Consumption",
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: ["Apples", "Bananas", "Oranges"],
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: "Fruit eaten",
        },
      },
      series: [
        {
          name: "Jane",
          type: "bar",
          data: [1, 0, 4],
        },
        {
          name: "John",
          type: "bar",
          data: [5, 7, 3],
        },
      ],
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <div id="container"></div>;
  }
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a feature called Shadow DOM which will encapsulate the template of your component behind a `shadowRoot` node. Therefore the `.container` div is not accessible via query selectors and Highcharts won't be able to find it.

Instead you can also pass a reference to a DOM element, and you can get such a reference from your template with the `ref` prop on any element, i. e.

```js
containerRef?: HTMLDivElement;

render() {
  return <div ref={el => this.containerRef = el} />;
}
```

And then you can pass that into your Highchart creation code, but you'll have to do this in the `componentDidLoad` callback because the container reference will only be availble then.

```js
componentDidLoad() {
  if (!this.containerRef) {
    return; // just a fail-safe
  }

  Highcharts.chart(this.containerRef, options);
}
```

However it seems like you're only wanting to render a chart in your component and nothing else, so you could instead also use the component's host element (i. e. `<my-chart>`) as the container. The host reference can be retrieved with the `@Element` decorator and is available in `componentWillLoad` already.

```js
import { h, Component, Element, Host } from '@stencil/core';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';

@Component({ tag: 'my-chart', shadow: true })
export class MyChart {
  @Element() host: HTMLMyChartElement;

  chart: Highcharts.Chart; // only if you need a reference to the chart for later

  componentWillLoad() {
    this.chart = Highcharts.chart(this.host, options);
  }

  render() {
    return <Host />;
  }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help and good explanation. I have tried the both suggested solution and the second with `<Host />` was straightforward.

Comment: With the first solution I could debug and verify that the div-element was created/referensed properly but I got `undefined` when the app tried to render `Highcharts.chart()` part. 

Learning question: I thought `componentDidLoad()` actually rendered the DOM so all elements _are_ accessible. Can you explain why this is not the case for this Highchart example?

Comment: I’m not sure because as you said all DOM elements should be accessible already in `componentDidload` which is only called after the first render. must be sth else ‍♂️