# SVG renderer is not adding elements to DOM in HighCharts when used with StencilJS

Tags: highcharts, web-component, stenciljs, highcharts-ng, stencil-component

I have been trying to Integrate custom boxes with Highcharts in stencilJS by using render event callback and using that to plot the custom box using the renderer function. With ref to the answer to my earlier question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76209995/21861131

The problem is when I switch between pages or between the different components on the storybook, the custom boxes are not rendering again, I was able to see by console log that the SVG Path is being created again but it's not adding it back to the DOM.

How can I resolve this issue?

I have tried storing the reference of the created SVG to a variable and destroying it before creating it again but it doesn't work.

I have tried working with StencilJS LifeCycleHooks but it doesn't solve the root problem.

Comment: This topic should be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62286854/how-is-the-proper-way-to-use-highcharts-with-stenciljs